# Convert Unicode Number to Integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, unicode

I have some numbers coming in as strings using non-ASCII digits unfortunately.  I need to convert them to regular Ruby numbers to do some math on them.  So for example if the number-as-a-string "۱۹" comes in, which is 19 but as the characters "extended arabic indic digit one" followed by "extended arabic indic digit nine", I need a way to convert that to the Ruby integer Fixnum 19.

The problem is, [according to this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), there are 55 groups of 0-9 of these extended digits, i.e. 550 total codepoints I need to handle.

I already know that for a given group, the codepoints for consecutive digits are contiguous, so for example extended arabic indic digit 0 is U+06F0 and extended arabic indic digit 9 is U+06F9, so I can test each digit to see which range it's in and then subtract the zero codepoint as an integer from the codepoint of the character I'm looking at, to give me the regular Ruby integer.  For example, 6F9 - 6F0 = 9 (in rough terms, once they're converted to their integer code points).

But to do this, I need to create a giant lookup hash for these 55 ranges and that's a lot of typing.  I suppose I could translate the HTML table at the link above into a ruby map, but that feels hacky.

I already know that

```
"۱۹" =~ /[[:digit:]]+/
```

will be a match, but the question is "How to turn those Unicode digits back into regular Ruby integers?"

There has to be a better way!  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is relatively painless.

```
class DecimalToIntegerConverter
  altzeros = [0x06f0, 0xff10] # ... need all zeroes here
  @@digits = altzeros.flat_map { |z| ((z.chr(Encoding::UTF_8))..((z+9).chr(Encoding::UTF_8))).to_a }.join('')
  @@replacements = "0123456789" * altzeros.size
  def self.convert(str)
    str.tr(@@digits, @@replacements).to_i
  end
end

str = "۱۹ and ２５?"
str.scan(/[[:digit:]]+/).map do |s|
  DecimalToIntegerConverter.convert(s)
end
# => [19, 25]
```

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, that looks like it would work well.  I wouldn't have to type in the 55 ranges, but I'd still have to type in the 55 altzeros.  Which I can do ... But is there another way where I don't even have to type in the 55 altzeros?  A gem or some further magic?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `"0123456789" * altzeros.size` ensures that both strings have the same size

Comment: @Stefan, oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: You could also create a replacement hash `hash = {'۱' => '1', ..., '۹' => 9}` and substitute the digits via `'۱۹'.gsub(/[[:digit:]]/, hash)`

Comment: I was hoping the Twitter I18N gem `twitter_cldr` would have something built in for this but could not find any way to accomplish this with it. Anyone else care to verify?

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I'll probably end up doing just that.  It's just that I have to type in the Hash.  I'll actually use Nokogiri to parse out the digit code points from an HTML page of digits I found, with all 550 extended Unicode digits, and emit Ruby code from that.  :-)