# Validate Numericality Conditions on English & Arabic Numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, arabic

I'm using the following code to validate numericality in Rails:

```
validates :number, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 500}
```

And it works well, but then I added regex to allow Arabic numbers like this:

```
validates :number, :format =>{:with => /[0-9\u0660-\u0669]*/}
```

Here it accepts Arabic numbers but the condition `greater_than_or_equal_to => 500` is working only on English numbers and I need it to support Arabic numbers too.

Comment: The `/[0-9\u0660-\u0669]*/` matches any string. Use `+` instead of `*` to match at least 1 occurrence.

Comment: I tried validates :number, :format =>{:with => /[0-9\u0660-\u0669]+/},  :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 500}

But doesn't work (Arabic numbers now are allowed but condition 'greater_than_or_equal_to => 500' is not working )

Comment: Yes, because that is not so obvious. Well, try `/\A([5-9\u0665-\u0669][0-9\u0660-\u0669]{2}|[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{4,})\z/`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/eP4eP3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the digit can be defined as `[0-9]` and combined with Arabic ones, `[0-9\u0660-\u0669]`. We want to match `500` up to `999` first.  We need to combine `[5-9]` with `[\u0665-\u0669]` -> `[5-9\u0665-\u0669]` that will match `5` to `9` in both ASCII and Arabic notations. After `5-9`, there can be 2 more any digits, so we need to append `[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{2}` to it.

Next, we need to allow numbers more than `999`, that is, `1000` and more. So, we need to add an alternative branch `[0-9\u0660-\u066‌​9]{4,}`.

The whole result is

```
/\A([5-9\u0665-\u0669][0-9\u0660-\u0669]{2}|[0-9\u0660-\u066‌​9]{4,})\z/
```

Where `\A` matches the start of string, `\z` matches the end of the string and `(Branch_1|Branch_2)` is a grouping construct that may be turned into a non-capturing one by adding `?:` after the initial `(`:

```
/\A(?:[5-9\u0665-\u0669][0-9\u0660-\u0669]{2}|[0-9\u0660-\u066‌​9]{4,})\z/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP4eP3/1)

Answer (score 0):

For ROR users who want to avoid using `regex` in such case to allow Arabic numbers to be working with `Integer` DB field (not `string`), I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338708/convert-unicode-number-to-integer-in-ruby) a good example to convert Unicode numbers to Integer before validation, so it's still possible to use such condition:

```
validates :number, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 500}
```